# GWT: How to get a submission result out of FormPanel

Tags: java, gwt

The example from [FormPanel's javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) says:

"...Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html, we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for further explanation)..."

However the javadoc doesn't explain a bit about this topic. Has anyone found how to get the HTML response sent back from server after a form submission?

Answer (score 8):

Add a FormHandler to your FormPanel, and in onSubmitComplete you will receive a FormSubmitCompleteEvent. Invoke its getResults() method to obtain the result.

```
form.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() {
    public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) { // validation etc }

    public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event} {

         Window.alert(event.getResults()); // display the result
    }

};
```

Comment: Ain't working for me. event.getResult() called on GWT 1.6 on Mac returns null.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually returning something from the file upload? I.e. if your handing this off to a servlet, use response.getOutputStream().write("Works!"); response.getOutputStream().flush();

Answer (score 4):

Following the answear from "Robert Munteanu" you should look at:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent.html

And there you can see :

getResults

public java.lang.String getResults()

Gets the result text of the form submission.

Returns:

the result html, or null if there was an error reading it

Tip:

**The result html can be null as a result of submitting a form to a different domain**.

Answer (score 4):

This problem only happens in a debug mode. Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3832

Comment: This is the correct answer. In `Dev Mode` `event.getResult()` is always `null`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get result message on DEV mode with the following code:

client side:

```
FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
            FormElement.as(formPanel.getElement()).setAcceptCharset("UTF-8");
formPanel.setAction(sb.toString());
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
formPanel.setVisible(false);
RootPanel.get().add(formPanel);
formPanel.submit();
formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler()     {                  
@Override
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        String results = event.getResults();
    }
});
```

server side:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
```

Browser: Firefox 24.3.0, GWT Version: 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

//=========== in the client side:

```
SubmitCompleteHandler sch = new SubmitCompleteHandler()
{
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) 
    {
    //get back the data results that had input the .xml 
    String dpsString = event.getResults();

    //And do your wanted action with the result
    System.out.println(dpsString);
    }
};
uploadForm.addSubmitCompleteHandler(sch);
```

//=========== in the server side:

```
// parse and handle file, e.g. if there is an xml file
...
InputStream fileImputStream = uploadItem.getInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(fileInputStream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
...
//Response to the request with the result  
dpsString = doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();
response.getWriter().write(new String(dpsString));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried replacing local host with machine name it didn't help [some people say it helped them], but it is a cross domain java-script issue so I tried just using the URL pattern assigned in the web xml and I got a String result. for details look up rubber duck answer in this link

[GWT Blobstore error calling createUploadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476420/gwt-blobstore-error-calling-createuploadurl/17334782#17334782)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I constructed my `FormPanel` with the `FormPanel(String)` constructor. With the default constructor, my `SubmitCompleteHandler` just worked.