# GWT FormPanel does not submit the session ID after updating on GWT version 2.4.0

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

After I updated the GWT version on 2.4.0 and the GAE version on 1.6.2 the `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel` does not submit the `jSessionId` anymore. I discovered this bug when I tried to get the HttpSession (`request.getSession(false`)) in the servlet-doPost-method which now returns null.
In my deployed version on appspot.com the app is still working. So I analyzed the post-request with the chrome development tools and detect that the `jSessionId` is not be submitted by the `FormPanel`:

Development Mode:

```
Request     URL:http://halligalli:8888/_ah/upload/ahJtcDNzdHJlYW1pbmdwbGF5ZXJyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxhHDA
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:7181438
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryB1bDbQ8YLCAabTG5
Host:halligalli:8888
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/Mp3Streaming.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryB1bDbQ8YLCAabTG5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="newBlob"; filename="09Anything new.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3
```

Deployed Version:

```
Request URL:http://***.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZrLfT_jYLHJKBXRoWX9_DeeYoa3Ob-vY0bbOcAJ3bj9ihT7Wp5yPmM3yjhn2RBpJAE8Pr7fIA8O-rhY8k0ARTy7hyU3GU3Qw4WrTHvXcSJ9mXZndA/ALBNUaYAAAAATyp8A-H7HSFTkl5ekVfXgXOmd3gK2PQ3/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:7181438
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXy11Yxjeo1JfdJdq
Cookie:JSESSIONID=KOiv4hx1rqIJ1aZdP8CufQ ◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄HERE IS THE DIFFERENCE
Host:***.appspot.com
Origin:http://***.appspot.com
Referer:http://***.appspot.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryXy11Yxjeo1JfdJdq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="newBlob"; filename="09Anything new.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3
```

I am using the `FormPanel` to upload files which will be stored in the GAE Blobstore and I need the session object to get the owner of the uploaded file (every other RPC in the development mode contains the `jSessionId`).
Any suggestions?

Thanking you in anticipation!

Comment: Did the answer below help you? Please accept it if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your failing request:

> ```
> Request     URL:http://halligalli:8888/_ah/upload/ahJtcDNzdHJlYW1pbmdwbGF5ZXJyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxhHDA
> […]
> Host:halligalli:8888
> Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
> Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/Mp3Streaming.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
> ```

You're not sending the request to the same *origin*: your browser doesn't send to `halligalli` a cookie that has been set for `127.0.0.1`.

As far as I can tell, this is a limitation of the `BlobstoreService` in the dev environment. See [GWT Blobstore error calling createUploadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476420/gwt-blobstore-error-calling-createuploadurl)