# GWT+GAE: Session attribute, which is set in a RemoteServiceServlet, is null when access from a regular HTTPServlet

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, blobstore

I have two servlets in my GWT+GAE app. One is "MyServlet extends RemoteServiceServlet" which handles all calls from client. And the other is "Upload extends HTTPServlet" handles files posted from client as explained here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview

How can I access an object, which is set in MyServlet, from Upload servlet?

```
//
//MyServlet extends RemoteServiceServlet
//
public User login(String username, String password) {
    User user = null;
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class, "username == '" + username + "' && password == '" + password + "'");
    List<User> users = (List<User>) query.execute();
    if (!users.isEmpty()) {
        user = new User();
        User userDB = users.get(0);
        user.setUsername(userDB.getUsername());
        getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    }

    pm.close();
    return user;
}
public void doSomething() {
    //Never returns null. This is good.
    User user = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user"); 
    ....
}

//
//Upload extends HTTPServlet
//
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    // Always returns null. WHY?!?
    req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `getThreadLocalRequest()` in a non-GWT HttpServlet since this method is provided by GWT's RemoteServiceServlet. In a standard servlet you should instead use the request object passed to the doGet() or doPost() method, e.g.:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("user")==null) return;
}
```

Comment: request.getSession().getAttribute("user") returns null, too. Sessions aren't shared between two servlets?

Comment: Problem solved. This was due to a bug of Blobstoreservice. Details are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476420/gwt-blobstore-error-calling-createuploadurl