# GAE and GWT - response.sendRedirect is not redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

I am creating an application that needs an image upload function. I have been following [this](http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/12/tutorial-gwt-application-for-storing.html) tutorial and the [App Engine Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview).

The image is uploaded correctly, and the server is redirected to the doPost function of the FileUpload HttpServlet. I can read the blob key from the request and save it in the datastore.

My problem is sending a response back to the client. Everything I've seen points to using the response.sendRedirect function, but that has not been successful yet.

```
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet 
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
{
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);

    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("picFileUpload").get(0);

    ShipHull shipHull = new ShipHull();
    shipHull.setShipHullName(request.getParameter("hullNameText"));
    shipHull.setShipImageURL("/shipbuilder/blobService?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(shipHull);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String hi = "hello";
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

    Boolean test = response.isCommitted();

    response.sendRedirect("/shipbuilder/FileUpload?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&shipHullName=" + shipHull.getShipHullName());

    test = response.isCommitted();

    return;
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
{
    String id = req.getParameter("shipHullName");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    resp.getWriter().println(id);
}

}
```

I am trying to redirect the client back to the doGet in this same servlet. I have tried this and without the `gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` and the `shipHullName=" + shipHull.getShipHullName())` but the doGet function is never reached. I have also tried `https://www.google.com`.

This is all being done on a development server (haven't tried on the production server yet).

If you have any other methods of returning the status of the image save (like if a filename is already taken), I wouldn't mind trying something different.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck with the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just putting a string for success/failure into resp object.

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException
{
 try{
   processFileUploads(req)
   resp.getWriter().print( "Success" );
 }{
 catch(Exception e){
   resp.getWriter().println( "Unable to upload the file - Upload Failed" );
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've been slow to respond, but yes, I have tried this. The client is still seeing a null response when I use the writer. I have a feeling this is some special behavior with the blobstore since it is forwarded to this post servlet from another server processes.

I will post the client code next chance I get. Maybe that could shed some light too.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. I guess I was having the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476420/gwt-blobstore-error-calling-createuploadurl).

I had to click on the GWT Development Mode toolbox icon and add the webserver "ammo-box" (Name of my computer" and Code Server as "127.0.0.1". When I directed my browser to that development link, it all worked, even the answer you gave SSR. This was a domain switching problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can close the query by selecting your answer. If you feel the other answer helped upvote :). Keep stackoverflow clean.